# Piping Image stream to command line programs in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe

I am trying to pipe a JPEG file from Image Magik's "convert" to others command line programs in other to make a benchmark. Is there a way to force a program that doesn't have a built-in functionality to read from pipe instead of reading the file from disk?

An example of a program that has such built-in functionality is "CJPEG":

```
convert INFILE.JPG tga:- | cjpeg -outfile OUTFILE.JPG -targa
```

An example of a program that doesn't ":

```
jpegoptim --dest OUTFOLDER INFILE.JPG
```

Ideally it would work like this (but it doesn't):

```
convert INFILE.JPG jpg:- | jpegoptim --dest OUTFOLDER -
```

I managed to do this though:

```
BASE64_IMG=$(convert INFILE.JPG jpg:- | base64)
```

And:

```
JPG<(echo "${BASE64_IMG}" | base64 --decode) /dev/stdin | awk '{print $1}'
```

But I don't know what to do with that...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: My version of `jpegoptim` has the option `--stdin` to read from standard input. It also handles `-` to read from standard input.

Comment: What's the version number you're using?

Comment: `jpegoptim v1.4.1  x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

Comment: I found it here: https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim/issues/14

Comment: imagemagick's convert already produces optimized jpeg.

Comment: if it can read from file, you could use named pipe instead

Comment: Can you give me an example based on the above, please?

Comment: Still not working:

 convert -verbose INFILE.JPG jpg:- | jpegoptim -v --stdout --stdin > OUTFILE.JPG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use process substitution, *if* the reading program doesn't expect to be able to seek to random positions within the input. (That is, it can only read continuously from the beginning of the file.)

The incorrect version (programs need to be written to accept `-` as a filename meaning standard input; it's not something the shell does for you):

```
convert INFILE.JPG jpg:- | jpegoptim --dest OUTFOLDER -
```

becomes

```
jpegoptim --dest OUTFOLDER <(convert INFILE.JPG jpg:-)
```

The `<(...)` is special `bash` syntax to simplify the use of a named pipe.

```
mkfifo input                        # Create a named pipe called "ipnut"
convert INFILE.JPG jpg:- > input &  # Start writing to it in the background
jpegoptim --dest OUTFOLDER input    # Read from the named pipe; convert blocks until jpegoptim opens the pipe for reading
rm input                            # Clean up after you are done
```

Comment: Even following the steps given above, I was not able to make it work properly.